# Is it possible to opt out a phone number from AWS SNS programatically?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I am trying to find whether there is a way to opt out a phone number from AWS SNS programatically? I could find provisions

1. to opt in an opted out phone number,
2. list all opted out phone numbers, and
3. whether a phone number is opted out or not.

But I couldn't find anywhere on how to opt out a phone number programatically.

Kindly assist me with this issue.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

From [CheckIfPhoneNumberIsOptedOut - Amazon Simple Notification Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/api/API_CheckIfPhoneNumberIsOptedOut.html):

> Accepts a phone number and indicates **whether the phone holder has opted out** of receiving SMS messages from your AWS account. You cannot send SMS messages to a number that is opted out.
>
> To resume sending messages, **you can opt in the number** by using the `OptInPhoneNumber` action.

That answers #1 and #3.

I could not find an API call that specifically lists opted-out numbers, but you could iterate through the subscribers on a topic and call `CheckIfPhoneNumberIsOptedOut()` to discover the status.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a particular use case where you need to programmatically opt out users from receiving SMS notifications? Typically, the user would themselves control this by replying "STOP" to a SMS they received.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find any programmatically related solution. But I found a [command line solution](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/pinpoint-sms-voice-v2/put-opted-out-number.html).

```
aws pinpoint-sms-voice-v2 put-opted-out-number --opt-out-list-name Default --opted-out-number +61444444444
```